# nano.request() find by query couchDB

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

I need help with a function nano.request(). I try get data by a request using a cloudant (couchdb) query but i no have idea how make it and i search anywhere.
please i need help :P how search by query in a nano.request function??

thanks

```
var query = {
"selector": {
  "_id": {
    "$gt": 0
  },
  "Campaign_Id":9999
},
"fields": [
],
"sort": [
  {
    "_id": "asc"
  }
]};

cloudant.request({db: 'campaigns',
              method: 'get',
              doc: '_all_docs',
              qr: query 
            },function (err,data){
console.log(err);
console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? This [db.get](https://github.com/dscape/nano#dbgetdocname-params-callback) might be the call you're looking for.

Comment: i need make a query to filter for example "selector": {
  "_id": {
    "$gt": 0
  },
  "Campaign_Id":9999
},
"fields": [
],
"sort": [
  {
    "_id": "asc"
  }

Comment: So you can use [Cloudant Query](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#cloudant-query) for what you're trying to do. Keep in mind you need to create an index for this first. [Here's](https://cloudant.com/using-cloudant-query-tutorial/) a direct example.

Comment: However, my experiences with querying in cloudant are related to Cloudant Search instead. When I needed to mix the query to filter on more than one field (i.e. x > 8 OR y < 70) I found that cloudant query didn't support the functionality at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var testRequest = function(query){

cloudant.request({db: 'campaigns',
                method: 'POST',
                doc: '_find',
                body: query
                },function (err,data){
                console.log(data);
});


 }



  var peticion = {
  "selector": {
     "crazy": true,
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 0
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}

  testRequest(peticion);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, rather just a suggestion. Why don't you try using Search Indexes for your queries? I found they are really brilliant. I've moved from views and queries to search indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks good, but like [Rho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3858611/rho) said, you need to build an index on the fields before you can use Cloudant Query. By default, you have the primary index in `_id`.

You can build indexes in the Cloudant dashboard. Here's what mine looks like: [image: building a Cloudant Query index in the Cloudant dashboard]

Here's the syntax to build that index:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "Campaign_Id"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

The idea is for it to be a little simpler than defining JavaScript MapReduce views. Cloudant Query can also do ad hoc queries once you build a `"type": "text"` index, but that index is more expensive. More on that at https://cloudant.com/blog/cloudant-query-grows-up-to-handle-ad-hoc-queries/